# Scrollbar jumps when holding down mouse and moving off to side

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering whether this is just the way that browsers act or whether it's a CSS property that I can change.

Take this simple example I made: https://jsfiddle.net/ogLw3ptj/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box-with-scroll">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box-with-scroll 
{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Repro steps:

(1) Center the scrollbar vertically

(2) Click and hold down the scrollbar

(3) Move mouse directly out to the right

(4) Scrollbar "jumps" to top

I'd like to show a pic, but PrtScn doesn't show mouse pointers :(

Happens in all browsers I've tried in

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour, it repositions the scrollbar to the original location when you move the cursor out of position(there seems to be a rectangle around the scrollbar)

Related info:

[Source 1 UX Stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55623/why-do-scrollbars-revert-to-original-scroll-distance-when-mouse-is-dragged-sidew)

[Source 2 Bug Report Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27306)